# FPGrowth: Input data is not cached pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run following example code. Even-though I have cached my data, I am getting "Input data is not cached pyspark" warning. Because of this issue, I am not able to use fp growth algorithm for large datasets.

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

"""
An example demonstrating FPGrowth.
Run with:
bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/ml/fpgrowth_example.py
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("FPGrowthExample")\
        .getOrCreate()

    # $example on$
    df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (0, [1, 2, 5]),
        (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
        (2, [1, 2])
        ], ["id", "items"])

    df = df.cache()

    fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)
    model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

    # Display frequent itemsets.
    model.freqItemsets.show()

    # Display generated association rules.
    model.associationRules.show()

    # transform examines the input items against all the association rules and summarize the
    # consequents as prediction
    model.transform(df).show()


    spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why**:

Because `ml.fpm.FPGrowth` converts data to `RDD` and runs `mllib.fpm.FPGrowth` on this RDD. RDD is not cached and this causes the warning in `mllib` code.

**What can you do about it**:

In your code nothing. If you think this is a big issue (shouldn't be) open a JIRA ticket and create a pull request.

> Because of this issue, I am not able to use fp growth algorithm for large datasets.

It can cause unnecessary allocation and slowdown, but shouldn't be limiting. If you experience failure it is possible that parameters require tuning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did df_rdd = df.rdd.cache()
and then also I am getting this warning. Warning doesn't matter, but because of this, I am not able to use this algorithm for large dataset. (large means not even more than 500 items). Same code will work for a dataframe of 100 items.  I am facing this issue only while using ml.fpm.FPGrowth. mllib.fpm.FPGrowth is working, But I want to use ml.fpm.FPGrowth.